# WinApi динамическое создание эллементов.

Tags: winapi, windows, c++

У меня в приложении поля ввода создаются динамически заведомо неизвестно сколько полей создаст пользователь. В процессе работы программы, мне нужно будет определять в каком текстовом поле произошло событие. 
Как я понял сам элемент должен создаваться примерно вот такой функцией:

```
hEdit =  CreateWindow("edit", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT, hInst, NULL);
```

И тут у меня загвоздка с ID_EDIT, он же в каждом текстовом поле должен называться по разному, а сколько таких полей будет я изначально не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в таком случае определить эти ID?

Answer (score 4):

Создайте переменную счетчик, которая будет считать от некоего базового смещения.

К примеру.

```
 #define EDIT_CONTROLS_BASE_ID 60000. 
 int counter = EDIT_CONTROLS_BASE_ID;
```

После каждого создания элемента к счетчику добавляйте 1.
А-ля:

```
std::vector<HANDLE> editHandles;
{
hEdit =  CreateWindow("edit", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU)counter, hInst, NULL);
editHandles.push_back(hEdit);
}

counter++;
```

Как-то так. 
Или:

```
std::map<int, HANDLE> editHandles;
{
hEdit =  CreateWindow("edit", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU)counter, hInst, NULL);
 editHandles.insert(make_pair<int, HANDLE>(counter, hEdit));
}
counter++;
```

Если хочется потом "вытягивать" элементы для манипуляций по ID.